# Using NAudio to mix WaveProviders

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

I'm using NAudio to generate and play sound waves in runtime.

I've managed to get a sine wave generated using this tutorial:
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio.html

However - what I really need is to be able to add many individual waves to a WaveMixerStream, in runtime.

I understand that to do this I need individual WaveStreams but I don't know how to turn the  output from WaveProvider into a WaveStream to add to the WaveMixerStream.

I assume this isn't possible so altered the code to give a derived WaveStream Class.

I've added:

```
public override long Length
    {
        get { return long.MaxValue; }
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to get the position:

```
public override long Position
{
    get
    {
        return //What here?
    }
    set
    {
        // What here? = value;
    }

}
```

So the question is: 1. Will this work? 2. How do I get/set position?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `IWaveProvider` and `WaveStream` is that `WaveStream` supports reporting length and position and setting position. However, since you are passing in `IWaveProvider`, you don't know the length and you can't set the position. Simply do nothing in the `Position` setter, and for the `Position` getter, return the total number of bytes that have been returned from the `Read` method so far (just have a private variable of type long to store this).

Another approach is simply to copy the code from `WaveMixerStream` and make it into an `IWaveProvider` instead of a `WaveStream`. This will actually simplify it quite a bit, A lot of the complexity of `WaveMixerStream` is repositioning all the mixer inputs correctly when you reposition.

(By the way, in the future I will be encouraging people to use the `ISampleProvider` interface and there is already `MixingSampleProvider` that does exactly what you want. I've not got round to writing tutorials on this yet, but it is all in there)

Comment: Thank you for your fast and useful help. I think I've got it but may well be returning to this question if it turns ugly! Thanks again.

Comment: I actually checked in a (completely untested) MixingWaveProvider32 last night, so you can look at that if you want to go the IWaveProvider route.

Comment: @MarkHeath: Do you have a tutorial on using ISampleProvider and  MixingSampleProvider?